# Has anyone gotten Geektool to work on Big Sur?

Tags: bash, big-sur, geektool

I have Geektool running with several geeklets on El Capitan. I upgraded one of my Macs to Big Sur that had Geektool working before the upgrade.
Now, it does not auto launch at login, and when manually launched does not execute any of the geeklets. Furthermore, then feature where you can select to make a new script geeklet does nothing.
I can’t find a log file for the app and can’t create a new simple geeklet to test.
Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: This page at [RoaringApps](https://roaringapps.com/app/geektool) indicates it works fine. Make sure you're using version 3.3.1. I don' use GeekTool myself, so I can't legitimately make this comment an official answer.

Comment: This reference is just a checkbox that says it works with no information other than the version, which is the one I’m using. It doesn’t work for me and I’m the system log I found that the app can’t find a file it needs. It’s in a temp location, and apparently doesn’t get created there. I’ve seen no one else refer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the SIP prevents geek tool from working on Bug Sur. I went through the procedure to disable SIP and it works fine. As a developer, I usually always do this and had not disabled it after upgrading to Big Sur.

Boot up in recovery mode (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> ⌘+ <kbd>R</kbd> while booting), start a terminal, then enter `csrutil disable`, restart and it should then work.

To enable SIP back, boot up in recovery mode and enter `csrutil enable`.